# INSERT TRIGGER does not fire as expected in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert

I have a site which executes a query to add a record to a history / audit table. The data being stored includes a block of text which may exceed 255 characters, but the history table fields for `new_value` and `old_value` are character varying(255). When the previous value exceeds this limit, I get a value too long error. In an attempt to avoid the error, I created a function:

```
BEGIN
    IF char_length(NEW.old_value) > 240 THEN
        NEW.old_value := substring(NEW.old_value from 0 for 240) || '...';
    END IF;
    IF char_length(NEW.new_value) > 240 THEN
        NEW.new_value := substring(NEW.new_value from 0 for 240) || '...';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END
```

The trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_history_update
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE truncate_old_value()
```

Since I set the trigger to happen before the INSERT, I was hopeful I could truncate the data before the INSERT was attempted, but the error was still thrown. Is it possible to catch and modify bad data like this before it is inserted? If so, what's the best way to define my function and trigger?

Note: I used 240 instead of 255 in the function to give myself a little margin of safety.

Answer (score 0):

The length of the data is checked *before* the trigger is called.

Change the data type to `text` so you are not hampered by the arbitrary limit of 255. The trigger will guarantee a length limit anyway.